# How do we debug a ruby AWS lambda function locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aws-lambda

Typically, when developing in the server-based model, I run the server locally, include the byebug/pry gem, then add byebug or binding pry in the code, where the execution stops and I am able to debug the issue. But when using the AWS serverless model(SAM), I'm not able to find a way to debug the code locally. Do we have a way to debug ruby code locally by evaluating the expression in the terminal or adding a breakpoint?

Comment: You can (probably, I haven't used lambda functions on AWS) use something like Airbraike, New Relic and others, exception management services. You get detailed bug reports and error reports.

Comment: @Eyeslandic thanks, but that would be to track the issues/bugs in the code. My problem is around adding a breakpoint in code for ease of development.

Comment: Opinion: design your Lambda function with a [functional core](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/screencasts/catalog/functional-core-imperative-shell) and test the core with normal ruby testing tools, like RSpec.

Comment: @JaredBeck it may be opinion but thats probally as close as you'll get to a complete answer. I'm not really that well versed with AWS lambda's but the interface is extremely simply. Its simply a method that takes the `event:` and `context:` keyword arguments and does something with them. Both parameters are just hashes. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/ruby-handler.html

Comment: @JaredBeck a small illustration with an example would be really helpful.